# How can I embed a classic google map?

Tags: google-maps

I am trying to embed a map into my html code.

This is the map I need:

https://maps.google.es/maps?source=s_d&f=d&saddr=Av.+Andalucia&daddr=Carretera+desconocida&geocode=FcrYKwIdw5ax_w%3BFQyxLAId-qaw_w&sll=36.427964,-5.138029&sspn=0.004333,0.009452&hl=es&mra=mift&mrsp=0&sz=17&ie=UTF8&t=m&ll=36.464367,-5.173187&spn=0.110444,0.171318&z=12&output=classic

However, clicking on the embed/link button provides me with the following iFrame:

```
<iframe width="425" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.es/maps?source=s_d&amp;f=d&amp;saddr=Av.+Andaluc%C3%ADa&amp;daddr=Carretera+desconocida&amp;geocode=FcrYKwIdw5ax_w%3BFQyxLAId-qaw_w&amp;sll=36.427964,-5.138029&amp;sspn=0.004333,0.009452&amp;hl=es&amp;mra=mift&amp;mrsp=0&amp;sz=17&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;t=m&amp;ll=36.464367,-5.173187&amp;spn=0.110444,0.171318&amp;output=embed"></iframe>
```

which pulls back the new version of Google Maps and destroys my original route.

Anyone knows a workaround for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible that the Geocoding of that location is messed up. Why not use the lat/long coordinates as the destination and see if that works out for you before get the Embed link?

Seems like your destination is at `36.483361, -5.200168` in that particular map.